# Apostrophe parsing issue in Java while submitting JSON payload

Tags: java, json, string

I have my Java POJO class with getters and setters. In this class I have one field that should accept only the "apostrophe" character. Other characters must be rejected.

Below is code snippet:

```
@Slf4j
public final class JsonFormatConstant {

public static final String JSON_ALPHANUMERIC_WITH_APOSTROPHE_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z0-9'\\s]*$";

}

@Data
public class UserDetail {

@RegularFormat(regularExpression = JsonFormatConstant.JSON_ALPHANUMERIC_WITH_APOSTROPHE_PATTERN)

private String myDetails;

}
```

Now when I try to hit the JSON payload with the below info:

```
{
  "userDetail": {

    "myDetails": "myDetails's"

    }
}
```

I am getting the response below:

```
{
  "userDetail": {

    "myDetails": "myDetails&#39;s"

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to remove these `&#39;` characters when I supply a string containing an apostrophe?

Comment: Somewhere in code you haven't shown, the JSON is being HTML-escaped. Find where that is, and stop the HTML-escaping.

Comment: `&#<code>;` is a [character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), 39 in particular is the ASCII code of the apostrophe. You would either have to track down yourself why the string gets encoded, or you have to show running parts of the code. Looking at some data fields is not enough.

Comment: i have checked my code and found below is the HTML escaping happening..                                                                                                      
   public class StringEncodingDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if(p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
            String str = p.getText().trim();
            return HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(str));
        } else {
            return null;}
  }